# api 10 требуется создать бд на sqlite где взять документацию?мне нужно api 10

Tags: android, sqlite

нашел ссылки на урок с таким кодом но он требует api 21? есть ли другие варианты?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

  Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
  EditText etName, etEmail;

  DBHelper dbHelper;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);

btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

// создаем объект для создания и управления версиями БД
dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
 }


 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

// создаем объект для данных
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

// получаем данные из полей ввода
String name = etName.getText().toString();
String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

// подключаемся к БД
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.btnAdd:
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
     // подготовим данные для вставки в виде пар: наименование столбца -    значение

  cv.put("name", name);
  cv.put("email", email);
  // вставляем запись и получаем ее ID
  long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
  break;
case R.id.btnRead:
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Rows in mytable: ---");
  // делаем запрос всех данных из таблицы mytable, получаем Cursor 
  Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);

  // ставим позицию курсора на первую строку выборки
  // если в выборке нет строк, вернется false
  if (c.moveToFirst()) {

    // определяем номера столбцов по имени в выборке
    int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
    int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int emailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("email");

    do {
      // получаем значения по номерам столбцов и пишем все в лог
      Log.d(LOG_TAG,
          "ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) + 
          ", name = " + c.getString(nameColIndex) + 
          ", email = " + c.getString(emailColIndex));
      // переход на следующую строку 
      // а если следующей нет (текущая - последняя), то false - выходим из цикла
    } while (c.moveToNext());
  } else
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "0 rows");
  c.close();
  break;
case R.id.btnClear:
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Clear mytable: ---");
  // удаляем все записи
  int clearCount = db.delete("mytable", null, null);
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleted rows count = " + clearCount);
  break;
}
// закрываем подключение к БД
dbHelper.close();
}



 class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public DBHelper(Context context) {
  // конструктор суперкласса
  super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
  }

  @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
  // создаем таблицу с полями
  db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
      + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
      + "name text,"
      + "email text" + ");");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   }
  }

 }
```

Comment: А что именно требует `API 21`?

Comment: Activity implements OnClickListener

Comment: Замените `Activity` на `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: пробую хорошо...

Comment: OnClickListener требует апи 24

Comment: `View.OnClickListener` добавлен в `API 1`.

Comment: View.OnClickListener добавлен в API 1. – post_zeew помогло